# I found mvn dependency transitive not work, why it happened?

Tags: maven

my project A import a dependency jar B, and B import dependency jar C.they all use compile scope.
when I use "mvn dependency:tree" command to show all the dependencies, I could not found
the jar C in my project. And i also could not saw any jar C in my IDE External Libraries.
Is there some special mechanism in mvn?
I display the code below.

1、project A dependency gfintertrade-common-service-nearby

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.alipay.findataprod.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>findataprod-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../../../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.alipay.findataprod.service</groupId>
<artifactId>findataprod-biz-service-impl</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>Alipay findataprod-biz-service-impl</name>
<description>Alipay findataprod</description>
<url>http://home.alipay.com</url>

<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <!-- project depends -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alipay.gfintertrade</groupId>
        <artifactId>gfintertrade-common-service-nearby</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.20200930</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

2、gfintertrade-common-service-nearby dependency cryptprod-common-service-crypto

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.alipay.gfintertrade</groupId>
    <artifactId>gfintertrade-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../../../../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.alipay.gfintertrade</groupId>
<artifactId>gfintertrade-common-service-nearby</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.20200930</version>

<name>Alipay gfintertrade-common-service-nearby</name>
<description>Alipay gfintertrade-common-service-nearby</description>
<url>http://home.alipay.net</url>

<packaging>jar</packaging>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alipay.cryptprod</groupId>
        <artifactId>cryptprod-common-service-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.20180516</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

3、I found project A not dependency cryptprod-common-service-crypto

gfintertrade-common-service-nearby is from remote repository
[image]

Comment: Please add the POMs.

Comment: i have added the POMs. thanks for your watching.

Comment: You are using `1.0.0.20200915` version of `gfintertrade-common-service-nearby`. It could be a old version where it didn't include `cryptprod-common-service-crypto`. Try using the `gfintertrade-common-service-nearby`  version  `1.0.0.20200930` in the `findataprod-biz-service-impl`

Comment: Also make sure you do `mvn clean install` on `gfintertrade-common-service-nearby` before you use/compile the `indataprod-biz-service-impl`

Comment: gfintertrade-common-service-nearby is a jar from remote repository.